# How do I remove a temporary folder on exit in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am looking for a solution that would recursively remove a folder created with `Files.createTempDirectory()` when my (Jenkins) Groovy script ends.

If you read the documentation createTempDirectory() does not remove folder and even if you try to use the delete-on-exit, it will fail if the folder has other files inside.

Please note that I am looking for a solution that would not have to add extra code at the end of the Groovy script or to add try/catch methods. That's because these Groovy codes are compiled from multiple re-usable parts.

A working solution should not need to add extra code at the end of the script, probably using a hooking mechanism to register the directory removal operation.

```
import java.nio.file.Files
x = Files.createTempDirectory()
// <-- add some magic hook to tell to remove 'x' folder recursively on exit
// a lot of code I cannot touch
```

#### References

- [Does Files.createTempDirectory remove the directory after JVM exits normally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022219/does-files-createtempdirectory-remove-the-directory-after-jvm-exits-normally)

Answer (score 2):

How about below?

```
def result = x.deleteDir()
assert result
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below will remove recursively all files and folders from the temp directory on exit.

```
mydir = Files.createTempDirectory()
addShutdownHook {
    mydir.deleteDir()
}
```

This code works for normal Groovy execution but it fails on Jenkins Grooby based pipelines because:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field delegate
    in field closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@782f5796
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
```

So, I am still working on addressing the "CPS" aspect, the first attempts failed with the same errors:

```
@NonCPS
def mkdtemp(String s) {
    mydir = Files.createTempDirectory("cp-")
        addShutdownHook {
            mydir.deleteDir()
            println "cleaned"
        }
    mydir.toString()
}

node {
   mkdtemp('xxx')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `finally`?

```
def tmp = Files.createTempDirectory()
try {
  // do something with tmp
}
finally {
  tmp.toFile().deleteDir()
}
```